# Don't use plastic bottle too often or too long?

Tags: drinks, recycling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is refilling water bottles bad for you?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/is-refilling-water-bottles-bad-for-you)

Is this true that we should reuse plastic bottle too long (refilling it as a gourde at the office for instance), because the plastic will free some chemical stuff into the water ? It's preferable to use glass bottle ?

Comment: This question is about the breakdown of plastic releasing toxic chemicals into the water. I have heard this as well though I discount it since it cant break down quickly and take thousands of years ina landfill at the same time.  Voting to repoen.